# How do I import my own class in another folder into a jsp file?

Tags: java, jsp

In the same directory as my index.jsp, I have a folder called `132b`.
Inside `132b` I have a folder called `classes` which contains a bunch of Java files.

In my index.jsp, I have tried:

```
<%@ page import="132b/classes/*" %> 

<%@ page import="132b.classes.*" %>
```

The first attempt complained about an unexpected end of comment.
The 2nd attempt couldn't find the class I was trying to instantiate so it couldn't be resolved to a type.

How do I properly import/include the classes I wrote?

Comment: You realize that Java files are source files, that needs to be compiled, right? webapps have a well-specified structure, and class files must not be in the same directory as JSPs. The must be under WEB-INF/classes, and of course respect the package hierarchy. Before going further, learn the basics of Java: how to compile a class, what is a package, what is an import statement, what is the classpath, etc.

Comment: Import using the package name or fully qualified name and not using actual path. Java will take care of the path.

Comment: @JBNizet Okay well I put a class called `Config` in a `classes` directory inside of `WEB-INF`.  How would I go about importing this now? (I tried a whole mess of things which didn't work.)

Comment: You can't import anything in the default package. NEVER use the default package.

Comment: @JBNizet How does that solve my problem...

Comment: @JBNizet I would gladly learn the ins and outs of jsp and what not, but unfortunately I do not have the time (being a college student in the middle of midterms week with multiple deadlines).  I'll search for alternatives.  Thank you for being so "helpful".

Answer (score -1):

By default it will search Java files inside src folder till you explicitly set it to be something else..

Try putting 132b folder inside src folder and see if <%@ page import="132b.classes.*" %>  works.

I always prefer to import only classes which are needed in that particular page instead of importing all the classes of a package.

Comment: Where is this `src` folder relative to the `webapps` directory?

Comment: @KacyRaye it should be in the same directory as webapps

Comment: @KacyRaye Please share the directory structure.. Add it to your question

Comment: Decided to stick with php.  I'm much more comfortable with it, and there's a few less hoops to jump through.  With jsp there's like 3 or 4 different ways to include files and it really matters which one you use.  With php I just use include/require (once), and the syntax doesn't change. And the fact that I don't have to recompile every time I make a change is pretty nice.

Comment: While I have no idea how PHP works, I wish you all the luck for your project. However if we can close this question as solved the community will be helped by that..